# Transformation of Random Variable results in strange CDF

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm trying to transform a RV according to $Y=X^{-a}$ with $a>0$ and X being uniformly distributed in $[0,A]$:

$
F_X(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x<0 \\ x/A & 0\leq x \leq A \\ 1  &x>A\end{cases}
$

I tried using the 'CDF'-method, here is what I got:

step 1:

$
F_Y(y) = Pr( Y \leq y ) = Pr( X^{-a} \leq y ) = 1 - Pr( x \leq Y^{-1/a} ) = 1 - F_X( Y^{-1/a} )
$

which gives me:

step2:

$
F_Y(y) =  \begin{cases} 1 & y^{-1/a}<0 \\ 1-y^{-1/a}/A & 0\leq y^{-1/a} \leq A \\ 0  &y^{-1/a}>A\end{cases}
$

and then results in:

step 3:

$
F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}1 & y<0 \\ 1-y^{-1/a}/A & y \geq A^{-a} \\ 0  & 0 \leq y \leq A^{-a} \end{cases}
$

and thus $F_Y(-\infty)=1$ and $F_Y(\infty)=1$

So this is wrong, but where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with inequality manipulation, which is on the tricky side.  For the cdf of $Y$, we want $\Pr(X^{-a}\le y)$.

We separate out the case $y\le 0$, although there is no need to. If $y\le 0$, we have $\Pr(Y\le y)=0$.

Now we deal with positive $y$. We have $X^{-a}\le y$ precisely if $\frac{1}{X^a}\le y$. This is the case if $X^a\ge y^{-1}$, or equivalently if $X\ge y^{-1/a}$.

If $y^{-1/a} \ge A$, then $\Pr(X\ge y^{-1/a})=0$. So if $y$ is positive and $y\le A^{-a}$, then $F_Y(y)=0$.

Putting things together with the case $y\le 0$, we get that $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y\le A^{-a}$.

Now look at $y\gt A^{-a}$. In that case, 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(X\ge y^{-1/a})=\frac{A-y^{-1/a}}{A}.$$
Note that this approaches $1$ as $y\to\infty$, as it should.  The density function of $Y$ "lives" on the interval $(A^{-a},\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! But can you tell me in which step exactly there is the error? ( I edited the post to add the steps)

Comment: As a start, Step 1 is wrong for negative $y$. Negative numbers and free and easy inequality manipulation do not mix well. That is why I separated out that case in the answer, even though the density has shape $0$ up to $A^{-a}$, and then is non-zero.